# Dependency injection in for complex model names in Laravel routing

Tags: laravel, dependency-injection, routes

I'm using Laravel 5.8 and I have a model with a two-word name, lets say CurrencyNetwork, and I want to use laravel's magic dependency injection like the route below:

```
Route::get('edit/{currency_networks}', ['as' => 'edit', 'uses' => 'NetworkController@edit']);
```

And in my controller I use:

```
public function edit(CurrencyNetwork $network)
{
    //some action goes here
}
```

But model instance does not resolve and I get an empty model instead.
Is there a way to make this work?

Edit:
I was able to work around this by registering the parameter in RouteServiceProvider, like this:

```
Route::model('currency_networks', CurrencyNetwork::class);
```

I was wondering if there is a way for Laravel to bind the model by itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to match the methods type-hinted argument name to the same name as the route parameter/segment:

> "Laravel automatically resolves Eloquent models defined in routes or controller actions whose type-hinted variable names match a route segment name."

```
                            // 'edit/{currency_networks}'
public function edit(CurrencyNetwork $currency_networks)
```

If you want it to be `$network` then change the parameter name in the route:

```
Route::get('edit/{network}', ...);

public function edit(CurrencyNetwork $network)
```

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Routing - Route Model Binding - Implicit Bindings](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#implicit-binding)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't quite understand the paragraph before.